# Can any one convert sql query to hibernate criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have an `sql` query. Can anyone convert to hibernate criteria?

```
SELECT TH_ID,TH_NAME FROM t_o2_th_master WHERE TH_ID IN(SELECT TH_ID FROM t_o2_user_gameplay WHERE USER_ID=10010 AND STATUS_TYPE_CODE_ID=1303)
```

This is my entity class for fields name:

```
SELECT treasureHuntId,treasureHuntName FROM TreasureHuntMasterEntity WHERE treasureHuntId IN(SELECT treasureHuntId FROM UserGamePlayEntity WHERE userId:userID AND statusTypeCodeId:statusTypeCodeID)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
WHERE userId:userID
```

to

```
WHERE userId = :userID
```

Answer (score 0):

We can directly run SQL queries using hibernate. Hibernate provides two different types of queries

- HQL queries. We can do everything that is possible in SQL
- Criteria queries . We have define criteria based on objects.

Comment: yeah i have converted sql query to hibernate like this                                                                                                 SELECT treasureHuntId,treasureHuntName FROM TreasureHuntMasterEntity WHERE treasureHuntId IN(SELECT treasureHuntId FROM UserGamePlayEntity WHERE userId:userID AND statusTypeCodeId:statusTypeCodeID)

Comment: but i am getting error like this                                                           2016-01-08 12:43:19,070 test  ERROR ErrorCounter:54 - line 1:221: unexpected token: userId
 2016-01-08 12:43:19,072 test  ERROR ErrorCounter:50 - line 1:221: unexpected token: userId
 line 1:221: unexpected token: userId
 at

Comment: This is something like name query. I think equality missing there.    SELECT treasureHuntId,treasureHuntName FROM TreasureHuntMasterEntity WHERE treasureHuntId IN(SELECT treasureHuntId FROM UserGamePlayEntity WHERE userId=:userID AND statusTypeCodeId=:statusTypeCodeID)

Answer (score 0):

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Criteria criteria =session.createCriteria( t_o2_th_master.class );
criteria.createCriteria( "t_o2_user_gameplay", "user" );
criteria.add( Restrictions.eq( "user.userId", 10010 ) );
criteria.add( Restrictions.eq( "user.statusTypeId", 1303 ) );
t_o2_th_master masterList = criteria.list();
t_o2_th_master master=null;
if(masterList.size()>0){
    master=masterList.get(0);
}
```